# Python how to encode sequential list to look random

Tags: python, encoding, cryptography

I want to create a list of string serial numbers such that knowing a few, a casual user cannot guess others.

eg if I run the following, serial1 should look nothing like serial2 and thus could not guess serial3

```
def scramble(txt):
    # encoding happens here
    return str(out)

serial1 = scramble('123456')
serial2 = scramble('123457')
```

Any alphanumeric output is fine as long as it will have a  direct relationship to the input.
Hashlib would work but all output types are way too long and truncation introduces possible collisions
Perhaps some kind of simple symmetrical encryption?

Any ideas?

Comment: `Perhaps some kind of simple symmetrical encryption?` - when you tried that what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random) module. This will also you to create a reproducible list of pseudo random numbers. The seed value is from the time by default, but you can set it to a known value to get reproducible results. For example:

```py
import random

random.seed(1)

print([random.randint(1000, 10000) for i in range(5)])
print([random.randint(1000, 10000) for i in range(5)])

random.seed(1)

print([random.randint(1000, 10000) for i in range(5)])
print([random.randint(1000, 10000) for i in range(5)])
```

will return

```
[3201, 2033, 5179, 2931, 9117]
[8364, 8737, 7219, 4439, 2537]
[3201, 2033, 5179, 2931, 9117]
[8364, 8737, 7219, 4439, 2537]
```

If you care about collisions you could keep a set of items you have already issued.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is a one-to-one mapping, so if you encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... you will get a random-appearing sequence of non-repeating numbers out, given the same key.

For 64 bit numbers use DES. For 128 bit numbers use AES. For other sizes either use a format-preserving encryption, or else write your own simple [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) with the block size you want, say 16 bit or 32 bit.

Four rounds will give you a good enough random appearance, though not full cryptographic security. For that level of security, you need AES.

Comment: Feistel examples look like the right track but output the full ASCII character set which will not work for printed labels. I wonder how HW companies make their labels.  My new Samsung tablet has serial ' R9PT606EX4D' . It could be from a long list of random characters but more likely is generated from a  sequential list so more serials can be generated later

Comment: Encryption outputs a block of bits. To get ASCII use something like Base32 or else convert the number from binary to number base 62 (26 + 26 + 10 = 62) Using hex will give a much more limited subset of ASCII.